# Cannot open images

Tags: python-3.x

I just started to learn python and I encounter a problem which seems to be super easy but I did all I can do try to solve it but failed.
Here is my code:

#

It keeps telling me that cannot open ship.hmp. 
I typed this code according to a textbook but here I do not know what to do.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill(ai_settings.big_color)
    Ship.blitme()

    pygame.display.flip()
```

run_game()

> pygame.error: Couldn't open /Users/kobe24/Desktop/python_work/images/ship.hmp

Comment: import sys
import pygame
from Setting import Setting
from ship import Ship

def run_game():
 pygame.init()
 ai_settings=Setting()
 screen=pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width,ai_settings.screen_height))
 pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
 ship=Ship(screen)
 bg_color=(230,230,230)


 while True:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
   if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
    sys.exit()

  screen.fill(ai_settings.big_color)
  Ship.blitme()

  pygame.display.flip()
run_game()
here is my full code

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, you can [edit] your question and put there properly formatted code - in python indentation matters.

Comment: @Zizhen Shouldn't it be `ship.bmp` instead of `ship.hmp`?